# How can I do dynamic imports in Astrojs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, astrojs

I used to have this

```
---
import Github from "@/icons/github.astro"
import Instagram from "@/icons/instagram.astro"
import MapMarker from "@/icons/map-marker.astro"
import X from "@/icons/x.astro"

const iconMap = {
    "github": Github,
    "instagram": Instagram,
    "map-marker": MapMarker,
    "x": X,
}

interface Props {
    name: keyof typeof iconMap
}

const { name, ...props } = Astro.props

if (!(name in iconMap)) {
    throw new Error(
        `Icono "${name}" no encontrado. Por favor, asegúrate de que el nombre del icono sea correcto.`
    )
}

const IconComponent = iconMap[name]
---

<IconComponent {...props} />
```

but I was told that if there are more than 100 icons just by importing the IconComponent, not only would this icon manager import but also all the icons that are imported in the code and this would be loaded in each document that imports it, so the solution would be to dynamically import the svg icon

```
---
const iconImportMap = {
    "github": () => import("@/icons/github.astro"),
    "instagram": () => import("@/icons/instagram.astro"),
    "map-marker": () => import("@/icons/map-marker.astro"),
    "x": () => import("@/icons/x.astro"),
    "arrow-up": () => import("@/icons/arrow-up.astro"),
}

interface Props {
    name: keyof typeof iconImportMap
}

const { name, ...props } = Astro.props

if (!(name in iconImportMap)) {
    throw new Error(
        `Icono "${name}" no encontrado. Por favor, asegúrate de que el nombre del icono sea correcto.`
    )
}

const IconComponent = iconImportMap[name]
---

<IconComponent {...props} />
```

I did this but it doesn't work for me, I get the error: Unable to render IconComponent. No valid renderer was found for this file extension.

I even tried the meta.import.glob but it's still a pain in the ass

Comment: The `import("module")` construct returns a Promise.

Comment: "I was told that if there are more than 100 icons just by importing the IconComponent, not only would this icon manager import but also all the icons that are imported in the code and this would be loaded in each document that imports it" – Astro components completely run on the server. So I wouldn't worry about performance unless you experience as a problem on your server. Pretty sure this is going to be fine even with 1000 icons.

Comment: btw. you may be interested in https://www.astroicon.dev